# Confused about STS and WIF

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, adfs

I am building 3 new websites and want to use WIF4.5 for SSO across these 3 different domains. I have read tons of materials about the WIF, while I understand the principles and purpose of WIF I am still very confused about how it works in real life, please help me understand the following questions, many thanks.

All my sites will be hosted using shared hosting services.

1. Everyone is saying that there's no need to build you own STS, but if that's case where can I found external services I can use to sign in my users and what about normal user registration interface for new users? and What about my existing users?
2. If i only need to build claim based web applications, where do I get user identities from in a real production environment? Do I have to pay them or do they need to go through my sites to approve them?
3. Is it correct that its no longer possible to let user register on my websites if I use STS?
4. Do I need to enable SSL and buy X507 certs for all my sites if I want them to be claim based websites?
5. I want to have a shared user database to store all our users, old and new, does that mean I have to build my own STS?
6. What exactly does it take to build my own STS, can I pcik one of my websites to be my own STS provider for my own websites?
7. What does it take and cost to build a STS? like SSL, certs, other stuff?
8. Can I enable social sign-in like facebook/Google/Yahoo if my sites are claim based?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You definitely CAN write your own sts.
2. You can allow your users to register in your sts or federate with an external identity provider (google/facebook)
3. No, an sts is just a asp.net web app, users CAN register there.
4. No, although ssl is recommended when usernames/passwords are involved.
5. No, you can use an existing sts like the IdentityServer which allows you to use a custom MembershipProvider against your own database http://thinktecture.github.io/
6. Yes. http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/08/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web.html
7. X509 certs for token signing can be created with free tools like portecle or makecert
8. Yes.

Comment: ok, once again Wiktor, thank you so much. #2 Do google and facebook  provide any STS services i can hook up to? #7 So if i understand you right, thinktecture is an STS identity provider, do you know any other ones, like microsoft or what exactly should I search for in google?

Comment: #2 no, they don't provide stses. Instead they provide oauth2 endpoints, oauth2 is yet another sso protocol. If you create a new asp.net 4.5 web app it will support google/facebook out of the box. #7 adfs2 is a free sts from microsoft but it only supports active directory backstore. But writing your own sts is really easy.

Comment: very nice blog you have there, goes right in my bookmark, :-)

Comment: ok, btw, the tutorials you have on you websites are they for WIF4.5 or earlier versions?

Comment: I dont understand why everyone on the internet is saying that there's absolutely no need to write your own STS, when there is almost none identity providers ready to be use. I think I will do what you suggest, either write my own STS or use thinktecture. Thank you!!!! :D

Comment: All my examples target wif 4.0 in net 4.0.

Comment: all right, i am using vs2012 and .net4.5, so I think i will go with wif4.5 thanks

Comment: "If you create a new asp.net 4.5 web app it will support google/facebook out of the box" - out of interest, what feature provides this?

Comment: "No" for #4!? All token exchanges should be done over SSL. SSL reduces risk of MITM attacks. Of course it depends on the risk profile of your apps. Also, building a production STS is not as simple as it sounds. Mike, if you really want to dig into how things work, by all means go ahead and build one, or open up Identity Server and study the code. Because there are lots of subtleties and different implementations of the same "standards", you will end up spending a lot of time troubleshooting and debugging.

Comment: @EugenioPace thank you Eugenio, I think what Wiktor meant was that I dont have to pay for the X509 cert but generate one for free. I seriously don't want to reinvent the wheel and spend months testing and debugging. I think I might use what Wiktor suggested, use the one built by Thinktecture and move on from there. If only there's a STS service provider that I can connect my sites to, it would be great instead of having to go through tons of code and documentations...

Comment: @EugenioPace: building your own sts to issue tokens IS simple. If you rely on wif there is really low risk of implementing things wrong, wif is too high level.

Comment: @Mike yes, Identity Server (IS) is an excellent option if you are ok with "owning" the code, as with any OSS software. There are also "products" (including mine and ADFS) that do what you need. Contact me if you want details.

Comment: @Wiktor: yes, you are right, the simplest sts possible is actually very easy to build. Hey!, it's built with the default template and as you say WIF gives you quite a bit to start with. But very often you need things like: logging & monitoring, automation, extensibility, a management UI, etc. Later someone asks for SAML-P support, and then for OAuth, and JWT, then for a management UI...That's what I meant by "production". Identity Server is a production system. It is a non-trivial piece of software. But, as usual, there are cases were a simple, custom STS has its place.

Comment: @nzpcmad the latest web projects in VS included dotnetopenauth with support for FB, etc. Not related to WIF though.

Comment: thank you guys. I dont know if it is me who is extremely stupid or is microsoft just not doing a good job documenting their software. On MSDN you see information on how to build claim aware websites, but what is the point to build one if you dont know how to build an STS and there's none public identity providers on the web. It seems all these smart tech are built for large companies for their extranet using AD or ACS as authenticator. It should be possible to build a simple STS that does nothing but send tokens to all RP, while remaining the traditional parts such as login and registration.

Comment: @WiktorZychla do you know any WIF4.5 tutorials that show how you can build a simple STS as I mentioned above. I know you have your own tutorials on your blog, but WIF4.5 is totally different than .net 4.0.

Comment: @EugenioPace its a very interesting website you have there, i will definitely take a look at the services you provide later, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has the [Access Control Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147631.aspx) (ACS) which supports Windows Live ID, Google, Yahoo!, and Facebook logins. Unless you need to option for users to register accounts at your site that might be a good option.

Comment: thank you for your help, i have noticed ACS too, however in order to use it, you need to purchase a license in order to provide the namespace and namespace key in WIF4.5. Also I am quite confused how AD and ACS could help in a case like mine, 3 public websites with some protected contents and features. I thought AD and ACS are used primarily within an organization's intranet or extranet, which are not exposed to the "outside" world.

Comment: I thought ACS was free? AD and ACS are different beasts. AD sits inside your organisation. It's a credential store, ACS is part of Azure hence designed to be part of the outside world. It's not a credential store - which is why you have to authenticate elsewhere e.g. FB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a (1) free solution as an STS or (2) want to have your own Id store, Thinktecture's identity server is the way to go.

I have some written some tutorials on how to do it.

http://claudioasanchez.blogspot.com/2011/09/setting-up-thinktectures-identity.html

Comment: thanks mate, I had no problem running the IP from Thinktecture, the problem is that in V2.0 they only included cshtml markup files without the actual "code behind", everything is packed int dlls. So it's kinda hard to study it.